# Labels overlap on donuts graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, pie-chart, donut-chart

I'm working on a D3 version 4 donut graph to represent dynamic data with animation transitions. Some of the labels are large enough to be two lines and can be a very small percentage piece of the the overall graph. This results in overlapping labels.

During the transition / animation, how can I keep the labels from overlapping with one another?

[image]

* The demo/example I'm working from: http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9572040
* The current working code based off of the example ^ above: [Code Gist](https://gist.github.com/rnickmccandless/c1c2c08e0effdf426877d2724779b256)

In my research, I found solutions that would adjust the label's `translate` style after they have landed on their destination but the resulted in non-fluid transitions.

Comment: It appears the library is optimized for a smaller font size.  Your image looks different than the example code, so I assume you've modified your code from what the example shows.  Would you mind posting your current code up?

Comment: I added the code gist to the question.

Comment: The .em's at 135 and 139, 1.1 and .35 respectively - Have you tried making these two match?  Perhaps the second one is setting the height of the label?